# SVG image zoomed in mode does not show the scroll bars

Tags: iframe, svg, viewbox

All,

I have a SVG image in an iframe that I am zooming into using the viewbox. However, the browser does not show the scroll bars when the image gets too large for the viewbox. I presumed that the browsers (Firefox 3.5 & Chrome 7.0 tested) would automatically display the scrollbars but it appears not to be the case. As far as I can tell there is no way to view the whole SVG image in zoomed-in mode.

Does anyone know how to go about adding the scrollbar functionality in iframe so that however large we make the SVG image, we can have the scrollbars visible to navigate and view the image?

Thanks much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width and height attributes on the referenced svg, if they are bigger than the width and height on the iframe element you should get scrollbars.

Comment: Eric, thank you as always. I dont know why but we must have been doing something wrong, we did something and now we do have the scrollbars. Dont know what it is that made it work but its working beautifully now. Thank you again. Regards,